# How to convert India Standard Time to SQL date and time in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sqldatetime

I want to convert below date and time format to SQL date and time 
Thu Apr 07 2016 06:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
any one have idea Thanks.

Comment: What is the input string? Does it really contain both `GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` ? Did you try to parse it to a DateTimeOffset before sending it to SQL Server? What is the type of the column? DateTimeOffset (good) or just DateTime (forget timezones?)

Answer (score 1):

Since your string has [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value, I would parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset) instead of `DateTime` since it *can* hold the offset part.

But neither `DateTime` nor `DateTimeOffset` keeps time zone information, you should use `GMT` and `(India Standard Time)` parts as a string literal delimiter.

```
var s = "Thu Apr 07 2016 06:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz '(India Standard Time)'", 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `{07.04.2016 06:30:00 +05:30}`.

[image]

And I would insert this `dto` as [`datetimeoffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) typed column in SQL Server (with a [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) of course) since it saves offset part as well.

```
+---------------------------+
|   Time zone offset range  |
+---------------------------+
|   -14:00 through +14:00   |
+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a string, you will need to start parsing the date for the specific culture:

```
DateTime dt =  DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo("<your_culture>"));
```

where `<your_culture>` is one of the multiple culture names for your country  (see http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/)

then you can get the date back as an SQL-compatible string, with simple quotation marks included:

```
string sqlDate = dt.ToString("'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'");
```

Comment: DateTime doesn't support timezones or offsets. The proper type to use is DateTimeOffset

Comment: Off course, this will only convert between formats. From the question, I did not infer that he needs also time-zone conversion.

Comment: Storing or passing dates as text in the database is *not* a good idea. It's far better and easier to use date parameters and avoid conversions and formatting errors. For example, the format in this answer is *not* "SQL compatible". It may look like the ISO 8601 format but is missing the `T` separator. It will be parsed using the locale of the server